# How to add class to <ul> of dynamic_sidebar in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, sidebar

Wordpress automatically wraps up your menus inside a `<ul>` but I want to give it a class. If you do it like this

```
register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Before Content Area',
        'id' => 'before-content-area',
        'before_widget' => '<ul class="menu">',
        'after_widget' => '</ul>',
    ));
```

you get an  inside another  and I dont want that.How you do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather use `wp_nav_menu()` for that, where one of the possible arguments is `menu_class`, whose value (a string) is added as a class to the `ul` which wraps the menu. (using a `ul` around the `li` elements is necessary for valid HTML...)

This also allows to add a wrapper/container and give it a class, see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/

Comment: Good alternative but I still wonder how to do it with widgets if possible.

Answer (score 0):

In your theme directory: edit sidebar.php and delete the opening 'ul' tag and closing 'ul' tags. I don't recommend this, because it will leave orphaned 'li' tags, which is not well-formed HTML.

Because there is not such way from where you can remove ul from register_sidebar.

Other thing please set  'before_widget' and 'after_widget' to blank like below code because without ul tag li tag is not recommended as per html structure,

```
register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Before Content Area',
        'id' => 'before-content-area',
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget' => '',
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try with jquery also:

```
 jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.widget > ul').addClass('nav nav-list');
 });
```